# Why doesn't the imput binding work with the combobox?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Normally, with textboxes, I use an input binding to bind it to the command in my view model. I do it in this way:

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

This work if I set it in my textbox, but if I set it in my combobox, it doesn't work.

```
<ComboBox.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
</ComboBox.InputBindings>
```

How could I bind the doble click?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an interaction trigger from [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/):

```
<ComboBox xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```